# Why are all representations of split groups of real type?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

(I am using a throwaway account because I plan on possibly pointing to this answer in a referee report I am writing, and using my main account would be a bit too obvious.)

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a split semisimple real Lie algebra. Then it is a fact that all finite-dimensional irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ are of real type. This can be checked, for example, on a case-by-case basis by looking at the table on page 292 in Onishchik and Vinberg, *Lie groups and algebraic groups* (which however has numerous typos, see last page of Ran Cui, *The Real-Quaternionic Indicator* for corrections).

But of course this is not very satisfactory. Is there a simple direct argument that I have overlooked?

Comment: Doesn't the Cartan involution conjugate every representation to its conjugate?  (In two different senses of "conjugate".)

Comment: Because for split groups Borel-Weil goes through.